# Access caller script's __filename from within a module function

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

I'm using node.js.

I would like to access the filename of a script from within *a module function called by that script*. For example,

**exampleModule.js:**

```
module.exports = function(){
  console.log(__filename);
  // more code which may also use the filename
};
```

**example.js**

```
var exampleModule = require("./exampleModule.js")

exampleModule();
```

This will log "*path*/exampleModule.js". I would like to know how to make it log "*path*/example.js", and I'd rather not have to pass in `__filename` as an argument.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
module.parent.filename
```

A friend knew the right things to Google.